# Connecting C# and Microsoft Office Application

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a project for school. The project is to create a presentation software. Example of this is the Microsoft PowerPoint. My goal is to mimic its use, but instead of customizing each slide, the user must be able to upload documents(excel, power point, and word). After uploading, the software must be able to convert each page to a "slide".

My medium will be Microsoft Visual C#. I would like to ask for any reading material, tutorials or any suggestions on how i could attack this project. Currently I am able to get text from Microsoft word and printing it out in a RTF text box, unfortunately I am not able to preserve its format(font style, font size, etc.). Although I have added Microsoft Word 12.0 Object to my references in c#, i do not still know how it works.

My inspiration for this project is EasyWorship, a presentation software designed for church use. Their software can upload power point presentations only.

I do really need a lot of help. Please, and thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are going to have to get a bit down and dirty with the COM Interop Assemblies available via the combination of Visual Studio w/Tools for Office as well as actually having the Office Suite installed.

[MSDN has a run down](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the various Interop DLLs available, it may be a jumping off point toward finding the entry point you need.

Additionally, there are [various walkthroughs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for beginning development extending Office components, so that may get you a bit familiar with how to implement the assemblies in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Read this article from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870302%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

> You create an add-in for Word 2007 by using Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Second Edition. The add-in takes the structure of the current Word 2007 document, gathers information about all the headings, and creates a basic PowerPoint 2007 presentation, with corresponding Agenda and topic slides.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in mind is not an easy task.
Consider installing virtual image printer, [Virtual Image Printer driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imageprinter/) for example. Then you can open your document in an instance of Microsoft Word, print the document to the image printer, wait for images to be produced, then display images one at a time in your C# application.